# How do I correctly setup Gitlab CI for Google cloud with SQL

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gitlab-ci

I want to setup Gitlab CI to automatically test and deploy my Node.js project to google cloud kubernetes engine. I also want to be able connect to my google cloud sql instance.

Im currently working with Gitlab auto devops. I have connected my kubernetes cluster in gitlab and installed Helm, Ingress, Cert-Manager and Prometheus.

After a bit of reseach i found out, that i have to deploy a Cloud SQL Proxy to be able to access the sql instance from my Node.js server.

My Dockerfile configuraton:

```
FROM node:10.16.3

# Intsall Google Cloud SQL Proxy
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy
RUN chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy
RUN ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=myProject:zone:name=tcp:3306

# Node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm config set "@fortawesome:registry" https://npm.fontawesome.com/
RUN npm config set "//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken" KEY
RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app 

EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

But this fails while building:

```
2019/10/13 11:48:38 current FDs rlimit set to 1048576, wanted limit is 8500. Nothing to do here.
2019/10/13 11:48:40 error checking scopes: *url.Error Get http://x.x.x.x/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/scopes: dial tcp x.x.x.x:80: i/o timeout | Get http://x.x.x.x/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/scopes: dial tcp x.x.x.x:80: i/o timeout
The command '/bin/sh -c ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=myProject:zone:name=tcp:3306' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Why does this error occure?

Do i have to write my own .gitlab-ci.yml configuration to handle such a common scenario?

If so are there any templates for this usecase, because all i find is just for manually deploying apps with docker to GKE with SQL?

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?  I am having a similar issue.

My current idea is to run the Cloud SQL Proxy as a container via kubernetes and then use that proxy to reach the instance.  This will require passing a secret so the instance can be connected to.

I have found these links useful, https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine and https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/.  But now my Pods are stuck in a pending state.

Comment: Did you review the following [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine#connection_overview_2) which provides templates and samples on how to connect.  Looking at the error message, it seems to be connectivity issue and it cannot reach the metadata server. Have you tried using [UNIX sockets](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#6_start_the_proxy) instead?

Comment: Pending state refers that Pod has been created and accepted by the cluster, but one or more of its containers are not yet running. This phase includes time spent being scheduled on a node and downloading images. Do you have any connectivity issue to reach gcr/public container hub or any other error message? @TylerR